# Recursive Patterned File Delete in Ruby/Rake

Tags: ruby, recursion, rake

I am attempting to delete files based on a pattern from all directories contained in a given path.  I have the following but it acts like an infinite loop.  When I cancel out of the loop, no files are deleted.  Where am I going wrong?

```
def recursive_delete (dirPath, pattern)
    if (defined? dirPath and  defined? pattern && File.exists?(dirPath))
        stack = [dirPath]

        while !stack.empty?
            current = stack.delete_at(0)
            Dir.foreach(current) do |file|
                if File.directory?(file)
                    stack << current+file
                else
                    File.delete(dirPath + file) if (pattern).match(file)
                end
            end
        end

    end
end

# to call:
recursive_delete("c:\Test_Directory\", /^*.cs$/)
```

Comment: In directory recursion, one usually wants to treat "." and ".." in a special fashion. If one doesn't do that, endless looping frequently occurs.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to re-implement this wheel. Recursive file glob is already part of the core library.

```
Dir.glob('C:\Test_Directory\**\*.cs').each { |f| File.delete(f) }
```

[Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-glob) lists files in a directory and can accept wildcards. `**` is a super-wildcard that means "match anything, including entire trees of directories", so it will match any level deep (including "no" levels deep: `.cs` files in `C:\Test_Directory` itself will also match using the pattern I supplied).

@kkurian points out (in the comments) that `File#delete` can accept a list, so this could be simplified to:

```
File.delete(*Dir.glob('C:\Test_Directory\**\*.cs'))
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize that `Dir#glob` supported the `**` wildcard.

Comment: Agreed...must better than reinventing the wheel.  Thanks

Comment: tighter: File.delete(*Dir.glob('C:\Test_Directory\\**\\*.cs'))

Comment: @kkurian thanks, I added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 12):

Since you're using Rake already you can use the convenient [`FileList`](http://rake.rubyforge.org/classes/Rake/FileList.html) object.  For example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'

FileList['c:/Test_Directory/**/*.cs'].each {|x| File.delete(x)}
```

Answer (score 11):

another ruby one liner shortcuts using FileUtils to recursive delete files under a directory

```
FileUtils.rm Dir.glob("c:/temp/**/*.so")
```

even shorter:

```
FileUtils.rm Dir["c:/temp/**/*.so"]
```

another complex usage: multiple patterns (multiple extension in different directory). Warning you cannot use Dir.glob()

```
FileUtils.rm Dir["c:/temp/**/*.so","c:/temp1/**/*.txt","d:/temp2/**/*.so"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Rake, I would use the `clean` task to delete files:

```
require 'rake/clean'
outfiles = Rake::FileList.new("**/*.out")
CLEAN << outfiles
```

Now if you run `rake -T` you will see that we have a `clean` and a `clobber` task.

```
rake clean    # Remove any temporary products
rake clobber  # Remove any generated files
```

If you run `rake clean` it will delete all files with `.out` extension.

With this approach you can choose to delete temporary files or generated files. Use the task `clobber` for deleting generated files, like this:

```
CLOBBER << Rake::FileList.new("**/*.gen")
```

You can see he definition of these tasks [on the source code here](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/d8aba43cfe7c42b16856c85dcc6ee3e2b9aff01c/lib/rake/clean.rb#L68-L78).